# Derivation of cross entropy loss in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, information-theory, cross-entropy

Given a dataset $\mathcal{D} = \{ (x_1, y_1),\cdots, (x_n, y_n)\}$, let's say we want to approximate the conditional probability $p(y|x)$, and we parameterized it as $p_{\theta}(y|x)$. So,for a particular $x_i$, the true distribution will be $p(y|x_i)$ and the approximated distribution will be $p_{\theta}(y|x_i)$, the cross entropy will be $H(p,p_{\theta}) = -\sum_{y} p(y|x_i)\log p_{\theta}(y|x_i)$. Now assume that $y_i\sim p(y|x_i)$, how to prove that $H(p,p_{\theta}) \approx -\log p_{\theta}(y_i|x_i)$?

Comment: I think you are confused with this *asymptotic * result https://jaketae.github.io/study/kl-mle/

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning, we assume that the true distribution $p(y|x_i)$ is an empirical distribution.  So with probability one, $y$ is equal to the true class.  All other classes have zero probability, and we get $CE(p, p_\theta) = -log p_\theta(y_i | x_i)$